# Raphael playground effect and fill opacity

Tags: image, cross-browser, raphael

I've written the following code:

```
var w = 800;
var h = 600;

var paper = Raphael(0, 0, w, h);

paper.image("http://static.pourfemme.it/pfmoda/fotogallery/625X0/63617/borsa-alviero-martini-rodeo-drive.jpg", 0, 0, w, h); 

var c = paper.circle(400, 300, 1);

c.attr({stroke: "#999", "stroke-width": w*2});

anim = Raphael.animation({r: w*2}, 6000);

c.animate(anim.delay(100));
```

( http://jsfiddle.net/qAgy7/ )

I need to visualize background image when the circle enlarges its radius, however I have the following problems:

- I don't understand why the animation run slowly
- Chrome render the effect in different way (I see a polygon not a circle like in
  Firefox and IE)

Someone can help me?

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476092/raphael-js-create-transparency-thorugh-the-intersection-of-multiple-object

Comment: Not clear to me why two people asked the same question, but this should be closed as a duplicate. (I too new here to do so myself).

Comment: chris, quentin is my workmate, we tried both ways :)